# Way to show AWS API calls being made by Packer in post-processors section?

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, packer

I have a Packer template with the following `post-processors` section:

```
  "post-processors": [
    {
      "type": "amazon-import",
      "ami_name": "my_image-{{user `os_version`}}",
      "access_key": "{{user `aws_access_key`}}",
      "secret_key": "{{user `aws_secret_key`}}",
      "region": "us-east-1",
      "s3_bucket_name": "my_s3_bucket",
      "tags": {
        "Description": "Packer build {{timestamp}}",
        "Version": "{{user `build_version`}}"
      },
      "only": ["aws"]
    }
```

I'm trying to debug a policy/permissions issue and wanted to see more details as to what AWS API calls Packer is making here with the amazon-import Post-Processor.

I'm aware of the PACKER_LOG=1 environment variable, but is there anything more verbose than this? This output doesn't give me much to go on:

```
2017/08/11 23:55:24 packer: 2017/08/11 23:55:24 Waiting for state to become: completed
2017/08/11 23:55:24 packer: 2017/08/11 23:55:24 Using 2s as polling delay (change with AWS_POLL_DELAY_SECONDS)
2017/08/11 23:55:24 packer: 2017/08/11 23:55:24 Allowing 300s to complete (change with AWS_TIMEOUT_SECONDS)
2017/08/12 00:29:59 ui:     aws (amazon-import): Import task import-ami-fg0qxxdb complete
    aws (amazon-import): Import task import-ami-fg0qxxdb complete
2017/08/12 00:29:59 ui:     aws (amazon-import): Starting rename of AMI (ami-c01125bb)
    aws (amazon-import): Starting rename of AMI (ami-c01125bb)
2017/08/12 00:29:59 ui:     aws (amazon-import): Waiting for AMI rename to complete (may take a while)
2017/08/12 00:29:59 packer: 2017/08/12 00:29:59 Waiting for state to become: available
    aws (amazon-import): Waiting for AMI rename to complete (may take a while)
2017/08/12 00:29:59 packer: 2017/08/12 00:29:59 Using 2s as polling delay (change with AWS_POLL_DELAY_SECONDS)
2017/08/12 00:29:59 packer: 2017/08/12 00:29:59 Allowing 300s to complete (change with AWS_TIMEOUT_SECONDS)
2017/08/12 00:29:59 packer: 2017/08/12 00:29:59 Error on AMIStateRefresh: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
2017/08/12 00:29:59 packer:     status code: 403, request id: f53ea750-788e-4213-accc-def6ca459113
2017/08/12 00:29:59 [INFO] (telemetry) ending amazon-import
2017/08/12 00:29:59 [INFO] (telemetry) found error: Error waiting for AMI (ami-3f132744): UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
    status code: 403, request id: f53ea750-788e-4213-accc-def6ca459113
2017/08/12 00:29:59 Deleting original artifact for build 'aws'
2017/08/12 00:29:59 ui error: Build 'aws' errored: 1 error(s) occurred:

* Post-processor failed: Error waiting for AMI (ami-3f132744): UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
    status code: 403, request id: f53ea750-788e-4213-accc-def6ca459113
2017/08/12 00:29:59 Builds completed. Waiting on interrupt barrier...
2017/08/12 00:29:59 machine readable: error-count []string{"1"}
2017/08/12 00:29:59 ui error:
==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
2017/08/12 00:29:59 machine readable: aws,error []string{"1 error(s) occurred:\n\n* Post-processor failed: Error waiting for AMI (ami-3f132744): UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.\n\tstatus code: 403, request id: f53ea750-788e-4213-accc-def6ca459113"}
Build 'aws' errored: 1 error(s) occurred:

2017/08/12 00:29:59 ui error: --> aws: 1 error(s) occurred:

* Post-processor failed: Error waiting for AMI (ami-3f132744): UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
    status code: 403, request id: f53ea750-788e-4213-accc-def6ca459113
2017/08/12 00:29:59 ui:
==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
* Post-processor failed: Error waiting for AMI (ami-3f132744): UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
    status code: 403, request id: f53ea750-788e-4213-accc-def6ca459113

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> aws: 1 error(s) occurred:

* Post-processor failed: Error waiting for AMI (ami-3f132744): UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
    status code: 403, request id: f53ea750-788e-4213-accc-def6ca459113

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
2017/08/12 00:30:00 [WARN] (telemetry) Error finalizing report. This is safe to ignore. Post https://checkpoint-api.hashicorp.com/v1/telemetry/packer: context deadline exceeded
2017/08/12 00:30:00 waiting for all plugin processes to complete...
2017/08/12 00:30:00 /usr/local/bin/packer: plugin process exited
2017/08/12 00:30:00 /usr/local/bin/packer: plugin process exited
2017/08/12 00:30:00 /usr/local/bin/packer: plugin process exited
```

I'm assuming this is a policy permissions issue but I can't tell what I'm missing from the above output.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no more debugging to enable.

I recommend that that you review that you have created all policies according to the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html) and review the permission for the user. You can do that by pasting the ACCESS KEY ID in *Search IAM*.

As an last resource it can be good to go through the process manually with the AWS cli.

Answer (score 1):

Not within Packer, but you could use AWS CloudTrail to see which API's have been called:

https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/